# Flutter Closing Dialog isn't working - error _debugLocked'

Tags: flutter

I have a button when pressed it opens a dialog like this:

```
TextButton(
       onPressed: () {
         showDialog(
             context: context, builder: (_) => ReviewDialog(context));
       },
    )
```

and the Review Dialog code is the below, inside it there is a button when pressed it calls a future function to add some data to firestore.

```
Widget ReviewDialog(dialogcontext) {
return Dialog(
  child: ElevatedButton(
         onPressed: () {SendReview(dialogcontext);}
  );
}
```

now the objective is from this future function, after adding the data to database, I would like to close the dialog. the code is:

```
   Future SendReview(dialogcontext) async {
CollectionReference reviewscollectionref =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ReviewsCollection');
QuerySnapshot firstquerySnapshot = await reviewscollectionref
    .where('Review_globalid', isEqualTo: globaluserid)
    .where('Review_bpid', isEqualTo: selectedbusinessprofileid)
    .get();
     
      reviewscollectionref.add({
    'Review_globalid': globaluserid,
    'Review_globalname': globalusername,
    'Review_date': DateTime.now(),
    'Review_bpid': selectedbusinessprofileid,
    'Review_description': reviewcontroller.text,
    'Review_status': "Active",
  });

     Flushbar(
    title: "Success",
    message: "Review is added successfully",
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
  )..show(context);  ///here I am showing the flushbar in the original page.

  Navigator.of(dialogcontext, rootNavigator: true).pop(); // here I would like to close the dialog.
}
```

the problem is, the code like this is giving the error: !_debugLocked'

I did some search and understood that this is because it is Future function, I tried the below solutions but didn't solve the issue:

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
Navigator. ...
});
```

in this solution, no error but dialog doesn't close.

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
Navigator. ...
 });
```

and this one is generating error: Route Lifecycle.pop.index)': is not true

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by moving `Navigator.of(dialogcontext, rootNavigator: true).pop()` to be after calling the function, instead of calling it from inside the function:

```
     Widget ReviewDialog(dialogcontext) {
return Dialog(
  child: ElevatedButton(
         onPressed: () {SendReview(dialogcontext);
           Navigator.of(dialogcontext, rootNavigator: true).pop()
          }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have workaround for this. I made separated file for showing dialog `dialog_success.dart`. Then inside that file I have function:

```dart
showSuccessDialog(BuildContext context) {
  ...
}
```

After that I put showDialog function inside that. It will look like this:

```dart
showSuccessDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
     context: context,
     builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
           ...
        );
     }
  );
}
```

In your case, you should show flushbar only when the dialog is closed (after pop). So put flushbar inside `.then` on the dialog. You can create variable to check whether it success or not using `isSuccess`

```dart
showSuccessDialog(BuildContext context) {
  bool isSuccess = false;

  showDialog(
   ...
  ).then((value) {
    if (isSuccess) {
      //show flushbar
    }
  });
}
```